# Pass value form one tab to other in CAB application

Tags: c#

I am creating a application using Composite UI Application Block(CAB).I have taken a **TabWorkspace**.
My problem is that I am taking a handle of a cam device in one tab and want to pass the handle in other tab.
Any one can suggest how to pass the value in one tab to other.

Answer (score -1):

Make a common.cs file. you have to assign first in an bvariable in cs file and get it